# How to fully reinstall a package on debian

Tags: debian, package-management, apt-get, nginx

i accidentally removed the /etc/init.d/nginx file and the /etc/nginx folder.

how can i fully reinstall nginx with reverting all confs to defaults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the package name for nginx is nginx

`sudo apt-get purge nginx`

Purge will remove conf files and such

`sudo apt-get install nginx`

to reinstall